# Rails/Devise: How to modiy the controller for /users/edit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I use Devise and right now `/users/edit` contains only Devise's password change form. I want to add a user settings form.

I am new to Rails, what is the best way to do this?

The **view** for `/users/edit` seems to be in `/app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb`.
The **controller** for `/users/edit` is nowhere to be found. How to extract it from Rails's magic so that I can modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate view is `app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb`. You dont need controller to add additional fields into the registrations form, even if its a nested form fields of another model. Just make appropriate changes in your User model to save nested associations (accepts_nested_attributes_for), attr_accessible etc.

Comment: Thanks! I did as you said, it works but users should not HAVE to enter a new password every time they want to edit one of their settings. I created a separate (similar) form_for, but if a user changes his city without filling the password change form, an error comes: `Please enter your current password`. Even though he clicked on the Update button of the second (non passwords-related) form. Any idea?

Comment: Read through the devise wiki about this. There's an article precisely about removing the need for this. Just think about any security impacts this might have.

Comment: @Jenny: Are you referring to https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password ? It talks about removing :current_password altogether, so it is a different problem. I don't want to change the way the password change form works. I just want a user to be able to change his city without having to care about passwords. Two different forms.

Comment: ok, not sure how you'd do that part. We had a similar issue and think we ended up creating a separate model for it. Then gave our users an account link where they could edit the basics and another page to edit contact details. Or just use a nested form in one view. Worth a shot

Comment: Thanks Jenny, I will try your approach with a "UserInfo" resource. It will result in more time-consuming SQL requests, but the least I temper with Devise the better.

Comment: I now have a UserInfo and it works fine :-) Accepting the answer, even though it might be more Jenny's that tipped me to create a UserInfo.